# Error: grub_is_shim_lock_enabled , portable linux m.2 drive on any computer (garuda linux)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot

Error: `grub_is_shim_lock_enabled` , prevents me from using my portable linux m.2 drive on any computer

I know that this error appears to prevent unauthorized users from booting your Linux drive on any computer other than yours!

the goal I want to reach is :

> How to make my external m.2 Linux run on any computer, Just plug and run!!!!

```
Loading Linux Linux-zen...
error: symbol `grub_is_shim_lock_enabled` not found
Loading initial ramdisk
error: symbol `grub_is_shim_lock_enabled` not found

press any key to continue
```

don't recommend me to do live-boot iso from a USB stick and then do chroot to do:

`grub-install --disable-shim-lock`

also tried :
to install refind and all those help me in rebooting on the main computer, but I want my external m.2 Linux to be directly bootable on any computer (not just mine)!

also, the errors are regenerated when unplugging my external m.2 Linux from the main machine, It requires me to do chroot reapply refind-install, and change the priority boot drive in bios, such a pain!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a (widening) problem.  [This thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=287024) from summer 2023 shows a couple of bugs filed in support of it, as well as some voodoo from recent followon threads, and most people's workaround:  downgrade grub for now until the bug gets addressed.